# unable to import android.os.UEventObserver package in android studio

Tags: java, android

My Android application listens to the `UEventObserver`, for that, I thought it needs the below packages:

```
import android.os.UEventObserver;
import android.os.UEventObserver.UEvent;
```

But when I try to import these two packages in Android Studio project, packages are not visible, why?

How to compile Android application with the above packages

```
 (public void onUEvent(UEvent event))?
```